# Match Payments and Orders PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables Orders vs Payments

Orders

```
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
|   id   |   Order   |  SaleDate  | Amount |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
|   1    |        H1 | 2014-02-10 |    300 |
|   2    |        H2 | 2014-02-10 |    110 |
|   3    |        H3 | 2014-02-10 |   1015 |
|   4    |        H4 | 2014-02-10 |    225 |
|   5    |        H5 | 2014-02-10 |    125 |
|   6    |        H6 | 2014-02-10 |    256 |
|   7    |        H7 | 2014-02-10 |     87 |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

Payments

```
+--------+------------+---------------+--------+
|   id   |  PayDate   | PaymentMethod | Amount |
+--------+------------+---------------+--------+
|   1    | 2014-02-10 | Cash          |    410 |
|   2    | 2014-02-10 | Cash          |    350 |
|   3    | 2014-02-10 | Check         |   1015 |
|   4    | 2014-02-10 | Credit Card   |    343 |
+--------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

I would like to match the amounts of Payments corresponding to the amounts of different Orders

is this possible?

Regards

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT * FROM Orders, Payments WHERE Orders.Amount=Payments.Amount` ? Bad idea, what is when you have more than one order with the same amount?

Comment: Does not look like there is a common key between the tables ? if yes whats that ?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Exactly there are no common keys between the tables, that's the problem the only thing in common are the amounts.

Comment: Store the related amounts (payments vs orders) in a table

Comment: @cazares What result would you expect if there are two orders for $100 and you get one payment on $100?

Comment: so what if for similar orders you have common payment amount ? the joining will not give you proper data.

Comment: Where is the foreign keys?

Comment: so if there's no reference between the payments and orders this will be an unsolved problem?

Comment: a piece of advice as a side note, you must store the idorder to the payment table for each payment, and trust me it will make life simple.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes i know, but so far the db from work is like the example, and my boss want me to make the relationships without this idorder (because they don't have it), they asked me to do that only with the amounts, but i'm thinking is not possible. Thx for the reply.

Comment: Add a foregin key to keep the relations intact.

Comment: @cazares there is no reliable way to join these two tables.  Tell your boss the database architect was a moron and all his historic data is useless, unless there are other tables that can relate payment id to order id